# How to build a C library for iOS by Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, c, xcode, static-libraries

I trying to build C library for iOS like the following picture.

[image]

I have build the `liblib.a` , but it compile error after I use `liblib.a`

The error log is like the following when I use `liblib.a`

```
file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/apk/Desktop/libTest/liblib.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
```

It seems the `liblib.a` not support for `armv7`, but I didn't find the armv7 and the arm64 in Build Setting -> Architectures.

How do I build the library of `C code` for `armv7` and use in `Objective-C` ?

**---------------------EDIT---------------------**

After I change the setting like the following picture.

[image]

It has the `.a file`. But when I try to use this library , it also show

```
file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/apk/Desktop/libTest/liblib.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
```

Did I missing something ?

**---------------------EDIT2---------------------**

I build the .a by following step.

1.Create new project.

[image]

2.Setting

[image]

3.[image]

4.[image]

5.put the **C file** and the **.h file** into project.

6. Press the build button

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like it's an OSX target, which doesn't run on ARM7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]You Want Creating library for ios see below picture for Architectures setting [image]

Try this

[image: Next helpful image]

Comment: I have change the setting and it has `.a file`, but it show the following error when I use the library.   `file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/apk/Desktop/libTest/liblib.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:`

Comment: your are yousing .a file another project ! that time this error is came ?

Comment: I create a new project and use the .a library , it show the `file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7):`

Comment: Which way you have creating the .a file means through script or lipo statement

Comment: You are taking OSX category Framework  , Take the ios category Framework

Comment: It build success , but it didn't show any `.a file`.

Comment: I am checking its creating build please cross check the , Project & Target settings as same as above images

Answer (score 0):

The Base SDK is set to "Latest OS X" not "Latest iOS".

Comment: I have change the setting , but it show the following error when I use the library.   `file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/apk/Desktop/libTest/liblib.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:`