# How to integrating Universal Framework , Written in Pure C API (CSDK)

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I am working on 3rd party Lib. let as call it Custom. After building Scon script i got for custom.framework , its has support universal arch like armv7, arm7s, arm64,i386,x86_64. 
The Custom.framework Drag into my Xcode project, then i found only .h fils. 
And its pure C function.

After that i did few build setup like, other liker flag, serach header path etc. but still i am faceing error.

```
"Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21"
```

I am think that few think is missing for setting this framework.
that custom.framework all API in Pure C. I am writing application in Objective-C.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778087/how-to-build-a-c-library-for-ios-by-xcode-6/26778315#26778315

Comment: @srinivas its not build . I need to use that Custome.framework API

Comment: are you integrating that frame work ?

Comment: yes . Its CSDK , All API in C Lag.